# Appending CSV to BigQuery table with Python client

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, python-bigquery

I have a new CSV file each week in the same format, which I need to append to a BigQuery table using the Python client. I successfully created the table using the first CSV, but I am unsure how to append subsequent CSVs going forward. The only way I have found is the google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client().insert_rows() method. See api link [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.insert_rows). This would require me to first read the CSV in as a list of dictionaries. Is there a better way to append data from a CSV to a BigQuery table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See simple example below

```
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()
# table_ref = client.dataset('my_dataset').table('existing_table')

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1

# The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
uri = "gs://your_bucket/path/your_file.csv"
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_ref, job_config=job_config
)  # API request
print("Starting job {}".format(load_job.job_id))

load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
print("Job finished.")

destination_table = client.get_table(table_ref)
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

see more details in [BigQuery Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_csv_data)